# How do I Adjust the width of a registration form to reach the edges of my screen on mobile view?

Tags: html, css, forms, registration

When you view this registration form on mobile, it is not wide enough.
How do I adjust the width to reach the edges of the screen on mobile view?

Below is the css and html code.

```css
html, body {
      min-height: 100%;
      }
      body, div, form, input, select, p { 
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      outline: none;
      font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #666;
      line-height: 22px;
      }
      h1 {
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 32px;
      color: #fff;
      z-index: 2;
      }
      h2 {
      font-weight: 400;
      }
      .testbox {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: inherit;
      padding: 10px;
      }
      form {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 6px;
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #095484; 
      }
      .banner {
      position: relative;
      height: 210px;
      background-image: url("https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-wFFHKlvZPDY/YOLgOyuQT7I/AAAAAAAAC7M/NZyy_gnRUTYim-svMak91e6JiHnA-mnsgCLcBGAsYHQ/s0/cac-office-hq.jpg");  
      background-size: cover;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      text-align: center;
      }
      .banner::after {
      content: "";
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      }
      input, select {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 3px;
      }
      input {
      width: calc(100% - 10px);
      padding: 5px;
      }
      select {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 7px 0;
      background: transparent;
      }
      .item:hover p, .item:hover i, .question:hover p, .question label:hover, input:hover::placeholder, a {
      color: #095484;
      }
      .item input:hover, .item select:hover {
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 #095484;
      color: #095484;
      }
      .item {
      position: relative;
      margin: 10px 0;
      }
      input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
      display: none;
      }
      .item i, input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #a9a9a9;
      }
      .item i {
      right: 2%;
      top: 30px;
      z-index: 1;
      }
      [type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
      right: 3%;
      z-index: 2;
      opacity: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      }
      input[type=checkbox]  {
      display: none;
      }
      label.check {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 5px 20px 10px 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      }
      .question span {
      margin-left: 30px;
      }
      span.required {
      margin-left: 0;
      color: red;
      }
      label.check:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 2px;
      left: 0;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      border: 1px solid #095484;
      }
      input[type=checkbox]:checked + .check:before {
      background: #095484;
      }
      label.check:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 6px;
      left: 4px;
      width: 8px;
      height: 4px;
      border: 3px solid #fff;
      border-top: none;
      border-right: none;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      opacity: 0;
      }
      input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
      opacity: 1;
      }
      .btn-block {
      margin-top: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      }
      button {
      width: 150px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 5px; 
      background: #095484;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      }
      button:hover {
      background: #0666a3;
      }
      @media (min-width: 568px) {
      .name-item, .city-item {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
      }
      .name-item input, .city-item input {
      width: calc(50% - 20px);
      }
      .city-item select {
      width: calc(50% - 8px);
      }
      }
```

```html
<div class='testbox'>
      <form action='/' method='POST'>
        
        <div class='banner'>
          <h1>Student Reg Form</h1>
        </div>
        <h2>Personal Details</h2>
        <div class='item'>
          <p><b>Name<span class='required'>*</span></b></p>
          <div class='name-item'>
            <input name='surname' placeholder='Surname' required='' type='text'/>
            <input name='first name' placeholder='First Name' required='' type='text'/>
             <input name='middle name' placeholder='Middle Name' required='' type='text'/>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class='item'>
          <p><b>Date of Birth<span class='required'>*</span></b></p>
          <input name='date of birth' required='' type='date'/>
          
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
          <p><b>Phone Number<span class='required'>*</span></b></p>
          <input name='phone number' required='' type='text'/>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
          <p><b>National Identification Number<span class='required'>*</span></b></p>
          <input name='nin' required='' type='text'/>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
          <p><b>Email<span class='required'>*</span></b></p>
          <input name='email' required='' type='text'/>
        </div>
      
        <div class='item'>
          <p><b>Home Address<span class='required'>*</span></b></p>
          <input name='house number' placeholder='House Number' required='' type='text'/>
          <input name='street Name' placeholder='Street Name' required='' type='text'/>
          <div class='city-item'>
            <input name='city' placeholder='City' required='' type='text'/>
            <input name='lga' placeholder='LGA' required='' type='text'/>
            <input name='postal' placeholder='Postal / Zip code' required='' type='text'/>
            <input name='country' placeholder='Country' required='' type='text'/>
           
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>Course Details</h2>
      
        <div class='item'>
          <p><b>Provide 2 Names<span class='required'>*</span></b></p>
         <input name='first choice' placeholder='First Choice' required='' type='text'/>
          <input name='second choice' placeholder='Second Choice' required='' type='text'/>
        </div>
        
        <div class='item'>
          <p><b>Course Nature<span class='required'>*</span></b></p>
          <input name='nature' placeholder='e.g  Food services' required='' type='text'/>
          
        </div>
        
        <div class='item'>
          <p><b>Office Address <span class='required'>*</span><br/> (Fill home adrress if none.)</b></p>
          <input name='office no.' placeholder='Office Number' required='' type='text'/>
          <input name='office street' placeholder='Street Name' required='' type='text'/>
          <div class='city-item'>
            <input name='office city' placeholder='City' required='' type='text'/>
            <input name='office lga' placeholder='LGA' required='' type='text'/>
            <input name='office postal' placeholder='Postal / Zip code' required='' type='text'/>
            <input name='office country' placeholder='Country' required='' type='text'/>
           
          </div>
       
        <div class='question'>
          <p>Privacy Policy<span class='required'>*</span></p>
          <div class='question-answer checkbox-item'>
            <div>
              <input id='check_1' name='check' required='' type='checkbox' value='checked'/>
              <label class='check' for='check_1'><span>I agree to the <a href='https://www.w3docs.com/privacy-policy'>privacy policy.</a></span></label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='btn-block'>
          <button href='/' type='submit'>Send</button>
        </div>
      </div></form>
    </div>
```

I have tried to play around with the codes, I adjusted the padding of the form and also the testbox but not getting the result that I want.

Comment: when i set padding 0 to .testbox your form using 100% width of screen in mobile mod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly you are trying to remove the padding from the .testbox element when viewed on a mobile phone but keep the padding when viewed on a desktop or laptop computer.

To do this you need to understand css [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

You could target any browser which is less than 768px wide with the following code. This css will not be limited to mobile phones but will remove the padding whenever a browser window is less than 768px wide

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .testbox {
    padding:0px;
  }
}
```